# CSS width 100% limited to browser window (it doesn't extend to right scrolling area)

Tags: html, css, width

This site is full-width and adapts to the size of the browser window. However, once the browser window is smaller than the content displayed, the title gets cut off once you scroll to the right.

The default width of 100% seems to be working for the width of the browser window only, not the width of the page! The same also seems to apply on the vertical axis.

---

## Example

```css
#title
{
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #404040;
}
#content
{
  width: 800px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
    TITLE
</div>
<div id="content">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

---

## Actual result

This is what it looks like when the page is scrolled to the left

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

*(For the sake of simplicity and privacy, content irrelevant to the question is censored.)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling a lot with positioning, I eventually came up with something.

```
body
{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#menu-background
{
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #404040;
}
```

**and the menu background HTML**

```
<div id="menu-background"></div>
```

---

`<body>` needs absolute positioning, otherwise the table of the content div will overflow out of the content div. Also, it needs a `min-width` of 100% to cover both cases: Either the window is smaller, or it's larger.

The menu works the same way, except that it is a single `<div>` that spans the entire page.

---

This solution works perfectly for both X and Y (menu and title) stretching and background color.

Comment: Thanks, this situation is (was) a real bugger. Not much info out there on this!

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that `width: 100%` takes the width of the window, but not the document.

This behavior is not entirely clear in the spec as far as I can tell.

> [**10.2 Content width: the `width`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> **`<percentage>`**
>
> Specifies a percentage width. The percentage is calculated with
>   respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. If the
>   containing block's width depends on this element's width, then the
>   resulting layout is undefined in CSS 2.1.

---

Two methods around the problem involve CSS positioning.

***1. `position: fixed`***

Fixed positioning makes the width relative to the viewport.

```
#title { 
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #404040;
  position: fixed; /* NEW */
  width: 100%; /* NEW */
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/)

***2. `position: absolute`***

Absolute positioning also works:

```
#title {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #404040;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/1/)

Comment: `position: fixed` will make the title always visible, even if you scroll down the page. That's not what I want.

Comment: I understand. It's just one method to get the width to expand all the way across.

Comment: But that doesn't fit my requirements. I could also always use a `background-image` as workaround. But I already use this workaround for the Y-axis! Any idea?

Comment: Absolute positioning also works. I updated my answer.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. The content is a table that has a certain width. And once the width of the content extends the browser window size, absolute positioning doesn't work.

Comment: With the code you provided in your question, both solutions I provided work. You can see that in the DEMOs. If your actual problem is more complex, then you may want to consider posting more code.

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/3/ - what I changed is adding **large** content, just like on my page. Content that is `1000px` wide. Once the content is bigger than the window, the issue can be seen.

Comment: Is the content width variable?

Comment: On most pages, the content is very wide, sometimes over 1000px. It's huge data tables. So it's very likely wider than the browser window.

Comment: I can alter any element I want. Can this be solved that way?

Comment: Consider including the TITLE in the CONTENT div: https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/4/

Comment: Putting it inside CONTENT seems like a good approach, but the content still has the width of the browser, when you look at my example with the table, which is more like my actual page: https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/5/

Comment: Instead of a `div` with a `title` ID, why not just use the HTML [***`caption`***](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_caption.asp) element?  https://jsfiddle.net/63ye4j58/7/

Comment: Looks great, but it is only for tables. If you take a look at my screenshots, you see that the content isn't just a table. There is a menu on the left and other content besides the table, such as `<h1>`

Comment: What *would* work is if the table did expand the width of **content**. Then I would be able to place the title inside the content! But the table somehow pokes through the boundaries of **content** instead of expanding them.

Comment: Unfortunately, fiddling with `<html>` and `<body>` background images also doesn't work. See my deleted answer. Defining both background images makes the menu background image cut off at page bottom.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with this two little friends:

```
width: auto;
min-width: 100%;
```

No `positon: fixed/absolute` needed